# drill down through json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

Im experimenting with the espn public API and am trying to use their json to access NFL player information.

the json im accessing succesfully looks like:

```
{
"sports": [
    {
        "name": "football",
        "id": 20,
        "leagues": [
            {
                "name": "National Football League",
                "abbreviation": "nfl",
                "id": 28,
                "groupId": 9,
                "shortName": "NFL",
                "athletes": [
                    {
                        "id": 14466,
                        "firstName": "Isa",
                        "lastName": "Abdul-Quddus",
                        "fullName": "Isa Abdul-Quddus",
                        "displayName": "Isa Abdul-Quddus",
                        "shortName": "I. Abdul-Quddus",
                        "links": {
                            "api": {
                                "athletes": {
                                    "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/football/nfl/athletes/14466"
                                },
                                "news": {
                                    "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/football/nfl/athletes/14466/news"
                                },
                                "notes": {
                                    "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/football/nfl/athletes/14466/news/notes"
                                }
                            },
                            "web": {
                                "athletes": {
                                    "href": "http://espn.go.com/nfl/player/_/id/14466/isa-abdul-quddus?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                                }
                            },
                            "mobile": {
                                "athletes": {
                                    "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nfl/playercard?playerId=14466&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 8645,
                        "firstName": "Hamza",
                        "lastName": "Abdullah",
                        "fullName": "Hamza Abdullah",
                        "displayName": "Hamza Abdullah",
                        "shortName": "H. Abdullah",
                        "links": {
                            "api": {
                                "athletes": {
                                    "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/football/nfl/athletes/8645"
                                },
                                "news": {
                                    "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/football/nfl/athletes/8645/news"
                                },
                                "notes": {
                                    "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/football/nfl/athletes/8645/news/notes"
                                }
                            },
                            "web": {
                                "athletes": {
                                    "href": "http://espn.go.com/nfl/player/_/id/8645/hamza-abdullah?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                                }
                            },
                            "mobile": {
                                "athletes": {
                                    "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nfl/playercard?playerId=8645&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 11910,
                        "firstName": "Husain",
                        "lastName": "Abdullah",
                        "fullName": "Husain Abdullah",
                        "displayName": "Husain Abdullah",
                        "shortName": "H. Abdullah",
                        "links": {
                            "api": {
                                "athletes": {
                                    "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/football/nfl/athletes/11910"
                                },
                                "news": {
                                    "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/football/nfl/athletes/11910/news"
                                },
                                "notes": {
                                    "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/football/nfl/athletes/11910/news/notes"
                                }
                            } ........
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
"resultsOffset": 0,
"resultsLimit": 50,
"resultsCount": 3301,
"timestamp": "2013-01-06T19:30:17Z",
"status": "success"
```

}

and heres the html / javascript Im using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON("http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/football/nfl/athletes?apikey=MY-API-KEY-HERE&_accept=application/json",
    function(data){
      $.each(data["sports"], function(i,item){
         $("#infoDiv").append( [i] + " - " + item.name + "<br>" );    
      });
    });
```

});

i can get this to display 0 - football   but cant use something like

```
$.each(data["sports"]["leagues"]["athletes"], function(i,item){
  $("#infoDiv").append( [i] + " - " + item.firstName + "<br>" );
```

to access the individual athlete data such as item.firstName , etc.

i keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: data.sports.leagues is undefined
```

what am I missing?   I'm using this same code structure successfully with a couple of other API's that provide json.   the ESPN json is a little more complex in comparison though.

thanks for any light you can shed on this for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sports, leagues and athletes are arrays, for example: sports[0] is an object (the one with name='football')
You should iterate each like this (not tested):

```
$.each(data.sports, function(i,sport) {
    $.each(sport.leagues, function(i,league) {
        $.each(league.athletes, function(i,athlete) {
            $("#infoDiv").append( [i] + " - " + athlete.firstName + "<br>" );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: works perfectly. thanks Pablo.  so where they are 'nested'(if thats the correct term) I need to step through 'each' level using .each.

Comment: @tamak You're welcome. At the level of each sports objects, both _name_ and _leagues_ are **nested** under it, the difference is that arrays have multiples objects at the same nested level, so you have to iterate them. If the answer satisfies you, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

`sports`, `leagues` and `athletes` are arrays which you need to iterate.

```
for (var i=0; i<data.sports.length; i++) {
     var sport = data.sports[i];
     $("#infoDiv").append( [i] + " - " + sport.name + "<br>" );
     for (var j=0; j<sport.leagues.length; j++) {
          var league = sport.leagues[j];
          $("#infoDiv").append( [i,j] + " - " + league.name + "<br>" );
          for (var k=0; k<league.athletes.length; k++) {
               var athlete = league.athletes[k];
               $("#infoDiv").append( [i,j,k] + " - " + athlete.fullName + "<br>" );
          }
     }
}
```